# How to view all events on a calendar?

Tags: calendar

Is there a way to view a list of all events on a particular calendar, in Calendar.app?

For some reason, I was sure there was a way to do this, but for the life of me I can't seem to find it today.

Comment: Which version of Mac OS are you using? You can find this by clicking on the Apple menu and choosing About this Mac.  For 10.7-10.9 you can search for "", this will show all of the events for the selected calendar/s.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that.  I'm running 10.9.1.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods:

- Enter `""` in the search box, and all the events will be shown in the search results.
- Go to Day view and scroll the list.